# Was Picard trying to take control of the ship to help?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In The Best of Both Worlds, part II when Data is connected to Borg Picard, Picard suddenly awakens and using his prosthetic arm starts interfacing with the ship. I had always assumed this was the borg trying to interfere with the ships operations. However, a short moment after Data breaks off the prosthetic arm, the councilor says Picard has regained consciousness. Could it have been that Picard was trying to take control of the Enterprise to help or communicate (as his capability of speech had not fully returned)?

Comment: I would guess that the prosthetic arm was pure Locutus, and the humanity that remained in Picard would be anywhere but there.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/175.txt)

> Suddenly...THE BORG ARM on Picard rises and attempts to disengage the connections on the biobed...
>
> THE SECURITY MAN charges forward... and the arm pushes them easily off the biobed... it moves back toward the connections,    but DATA grabs the Borg hand and holds it back from the controls    using his extraordinary strength...
>
> THE TWO ARMS locked in a symbolic arm wrestle for control of Picard... and finally after straining at both ends, Data wins by breaking the arm off at the wrist joint...
>
> THE BROKEN BORG 'HAND' continues to move in Data's hand...

So he (or the arm) wasn't attempting to take control of the ship, so much as free himself from the biobed. Had Locutus been able to get free, he probably would have tried to assimilate the ship.

As to why Picard suddenly started to wake up after this incident, perhaps the Borg started to give up on Locutus, realizing that he wasn't a match for Data.